# 1MB application using Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am wondering how to create Windows application with 1MB size using Visual Studio.

After searching google, I found that Visual Studio using C# language require .NET Framework. The .NET Framework is about 35MB size. For PC which do not have .NET Framework installed, I have to prepare instllation file, which may be 35MB + application file, or ask the user to install .NET Framework by theirselves.

I have been using C++ Builder for years. With C++ Builder, I can make application about 1MB size, without asking the user to install other frameworks. It is handy.

I wonder whether there is a way to make 1MB application without asking the user to install frameworks, on Visual Studio IDE. I do not stick to C# language, C++ may be O.K. But I am not sure what the alternative for .NET framework, in that case.

Comment: If C++ (using C++ builder) solves your problem - just use it.

Comment: @ zerkms That's one option I can choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop C++ in Visual Studio. The equivalent to the .NET framework would [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e.aspx) and the win32 api. Or you could use another C++ framework like [Qt](https://qt-project.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You need the .Net Framework for c#.  No way around it.  Most newer versions of Windows come with a version of the .Net Framework so depending on which version you target and which Windows versions you support, you may not need to distribute .Net.

Here's a post showing which versions of the framework come on which versions of Windows.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You mean, that if I build app for Windows7 using C# (targeting .NET Framework 3.5.1), the app can run on Windows 7/8/8.1 as Desktop app? Or the app run only for Windows7, not for Windows8/8.1 Desktop?

Comment: That is true.  I forgot that .NET 3.5.1 isn't installed by default on Windows 8/8.1.  You will likely need to distribute the Framework regardless unless you have real tight control over who installs it.  Another possibility is to distribute your app with the web installer of the framework.  This is much smaller but requires internet access at install time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The background of my question was the case when the user do not have enough broadband internet access for 40MB or so, but has access for 2MB/day. In this case, I may not use C# and Visual Studio needing .NET Frameworks. Tight control over OS (only for Win7 etc), may cause version control problem for the software.